# Why does python allow insert at an non-existing index but throws an error on accessing the same?

Tags: python, list, indexing, insert

```
# Can anyone explain what is happening in the background?
# 
thislist = ["0th index", "1st index", "2nd index"]
print(thislist)
thislist.pop()
print(thislist)
thislist.insert(2,"2nd index")
print(thislist)
thislist.insert(4,"jumped an index") # inserting at a non-existing index
print(thislist)                      # we can see it inserts at last index available
print(thislist[3])                   # prints - jumped an index
print(thislist[4])                   # error
```

Comment: because that was the design decision at the time. I don't think anyone can answer "*why*"

Comment: FWIW you'll notice that "inserting at a non exisiting index" doesn't actually insert at this non-existing index - it just appends to the list.

Answer (score 0):

That constraction will insert value in list

> ['1', '2'].insert(1, '12')

If you insert a value using an index which is more than `len(List)`, than insert will add that element at index `len(List)`. That method will try use minimum memory usage. In your example Python inserted "jumped an index" with the next available index `index = 3`. You then try to print the item at `index = 4`, which doesn't exist, so of course you get an error.

Comment: This does not answer the question  **why** calling `insert` with a non-existing index works without raising an `IndexError`

Comment: I think i gave full answer. That link https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html can prove my words. Method insert cannot raising list, because the developers made it memory-saving !!